# How to turn off macro hygiene?

Tags: rust, macros, hygiene

I'm trying to make a macro that pastes in boilerplate code and I would like to use the variables it pastes in afterwards. Rust's macro hygiene is preventing this; how do I turn this off?

I understand that there are ways to work around it, by passing all the variables into the macro, but that would make the macro useless... I found a crate called unhygienic, which states it does exactly this, but I can't get it to work.

This is how it's supposed to work. This is how you can use the Processing (drawing/graphics framework) in Java or JavaScript (this would show a moving car (defined in a `Car` class) and a rectangle:

```js
// You need to add a library or use the pde to be able to make this work though

let car;

setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 100);
    frameRate(60);
    car = new Car();
}

draw() {
    car.move();
    car.show();

    // this draws a rectangle at a certain place
    rect(100, 200, 200, 100)
}
```

`setup` is everything you do once before the main loop, and `draw` is everything you do inside the loop. This is how I would like to have it look in Rust (definitely not needed, just for aesthetics):

```
//does all the boilerplate opengl setup. 
setup!{
    // setting my variables and settings
}

// // adds a loop around the code in it and keeps up the framerate etc
draw!{
    // do my updating and drawing commands
}
```

Comment: There are some cases where hygiene is truly undesirable, but often there are better ways to deal with hygiene issues than simply erasing it. Passing all the variable names into the macro is one example, but you can also: put the macro declaration inside the scope of the referenced variables; invert the macro so the variables are already inside it; use multiple macros; or some combination of the above. Are you open to other approaches rather than just abandoning hygiene altogether?

Comment: It would be useful if you had some code example to illustrate what you want to do, so that we can better find solutions that fit your use case.

Comment: What I actually want to do it create a Processing (art/drawing/graphics tool from java) clone for rust. It works like this: you fill in a setup function and a draw function with calls like “draw a square”, and it renders that in a window. The important part is that is leaves out boilerplate code (which handles events, and keeps a regular framerate, etc). I figured I recreate setup() and draw() with macros, that fill in the rest of the code around it. In Java this is done through inheritance, and overriding setup() and draw() but that’s quite hard to do in rust.

Comment: To Trentcl, therefore the solutions would really desimplify the code, and add much more than a setup and draw function

Comment: I figured that if I used really strange macro variable names, the hygiene problem would not occur

Comment: Can you provide a pseudocode example of a program that would take advantage of this? I think that would help make it clearer what problem you are trying to solve. I have a hunch that there is a much simpler solution than unhygienic macros.

Comment: @Coder-256 its updated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a trait! This shows the general outline of how you could implement this:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e3bcd896e7f7623512503ea66a5fe4b)

```rust
// Library:
mod library {
    pub trait Program {
        fn setup(ctx: &mut Context) -> Self;
        fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context);
    }

    pub struct Context;

    impl Context {
        pub fn create_canvas(&mut self, width: usize, height: usize) {
            // ...
        }

        pub fn frame_rate(&mut self, fps: usize) {
            // ...
        }

        pub fn rect(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, w: usize, h: usize) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    pub fn run_program<P: Program>() {
        let ctx = Context;
        let program = P::setup(&mut ctx);

        loop {
            program.draw(&mut ctx);
        }
    }
}

// User:
use library::{Context, Program};

struct Car;

impl Car {
    // `move` is a reserved keyword
    fn move_pos(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) {
        // ...
    }

    fn show(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) {
        // ...
    }
}

struct MyProgram {
    car: Car,
}

impl Program for MyProgram {
    fn setup(ctx: &mut Context) -> Self {
        ctx.create_canvas(500, 100);
        ctx.frame_rate(60);

        Self { car: Car }
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) {
        self.car.move_pos(ctx);
        self.car.show(ctx);

        // this draws a rectangle at a certain place
        ctx.rect(100, 200, 200, 100)
    }
}

fn main() {
    library::run_program::<MyProgram>();
}
```

I know it is a bit burdensome to pass `ctx` around everywhere, but it is well worth it because you don't have to worry about using a `Rc<RefCell<...>>` (which can get even more complicated with multiple threads) in order to ensure unique access to a shared context via slow, runtime-checked memory management. You can run multiple programs at the same time, each with its own context, and you know that at any given time, at most one function is writing to the context.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked by the OP, it only provides a workaround. It's generally useful to *answer the direct question* to make the post useful to future searchers. You can then suggest alternative paths to solve the indirect goals.

Comment: @Shepmaster I am aware, but I posted this because I think using macros is likely the wrong approach (I have used Processing before, I know how the API works). If OP doesn't like my solution, they don't have to accept it, I am just showing how I would create an API that solves the problem, it's just an idea for an alternate way to solve the original problem.

Comment: I must say this it's a nice solution for my case! Will try to implement it some way, but i'll leave the topic open for others that really need to turn off the hygiene...